# getting only the date on datetime

Tags: python, django

Good day! I'm new in using Django and python and I wanted to check only the date in DateTime inside my database.

```
model = Employee_Salary

Employee_Salary.objects.filter(emp_id=employee_id, emp_in=datetime.today().date()).exists()
enter code here
```

so the code I'm currently using is this datetime.today().date() to get only the date

```
if Employee_Salary.objects.filter(emp_id=employee_id, emp_in=datetime.today().date()).exists():
                # if emp out exist then stop
                if Employee_Salary.objects.filter(emp_id=employee_id, emp_out=datetime.today().date()).exists():

                    messages.info(request,'you are already logged out...')
                    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', locals())

                else:
                    Employee_Salary.objects.filter(emp_id=employee_id).update(emp_out=datetime.today()) # should be emp out, rendered and salary
                    messages.info(request,'logged out...')
                    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', locals())

            else:
                #command if employee does not exist add employee
                register_emp = Employee_Salary(emp_id=employee_id, emp_in=datetime.today())
                register_emp.save()
                messages.info(request,'logged in')
                return render(request, 'registration/register.html', locals())



    #this is my entire code
```

I expected it to check my model Employee_salary's emp_in, which emp_in is a DateTime, then I wanted to check only the date and if there is a date already this day, it will now put a data inside the emp_out instead, but it didn't happen, it made another login of emp_in instead...

I really hope I explained it well and thanks in advance on your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compare only the date then you need to use **__date** attribute of datetime field.

```
Employee_Salary.objects.filter(emp_id=employee_id, emp_in__date=datetime.today().date()).exists()
```